# What is available for Roundhouse Token Replacement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, roundhouse

We're using Roundhouse to deploy our databases and keep versions for SQL Server (2008+)

I have a script which grants permissions and needs to have a username passed in. I know there is support for token replacement in Roundhouse, but the only token I've seen mentioned is {{database}}.

What built-in tokens are available?
Can users define their own tokens? Is so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time ONLY the items in the configuration - https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse/wiki/ConfigurationOptions

Note the full name of the option when using token replacement:

> -d, --db, --database, --databasename=VALUE | REQUIRED: **DatabaseName** - The database you want to create/migrate.
>   -c, --cs, --connstring, --connectionstring=VALUE | REQUIRED: **ConnectionString** - As an alternative to ServerName and Database - You
>   can provide an entire connection string instead.

It's the bolded name, e.g. "{{DatabaseName}}" or "{{ConnectionString}}" from the examples above.